# Parse JSON get from AFNetworking to display in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

Im newly using `AFNetworking` to get `JSON` and parse it,I've imported it to my project and got the `JSON` but i don't know how is it possible to parse the `JSON` for display especially in Objective-c.

Here is the code in my `viewDidLoad` to Get `JSON` :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The Retrieved `JSON` for parsing:

```
  {
        genre =         (
            Action,
            Drama,
            "Sci-Fi"
        );
        image = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg";
        rating = "8.300000000000001";
        releaseYear = 2014;
        title = "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes";
    },
        {
        genre =         (
            Action,
            "Sci-Fi",
            Thriller
        );
        image = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/4.jpg";
        rating = "8.4";
        releaseYear = 2014;
        title = "X-Men: Days of Future Past";
    },
        {
        genre =         (
            Action,
            Adventure,
            Fantasy
        );
        image = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/7.jpg";
        rating = "7.3";
        releaseYear = 2014;
        title = "The Amazing Spider-Man 2";
    },
        {
        genre =         (
            Animation,
            Comedy,
            Family
        );
        image = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/9.jpg";
        rating = "8.300000000000001";
        releaseYear = 2013;
        title = Rush;
    },
        {
        genre =         (
            Animation,
            Adventure,
            Family
        );
        image = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/15.jpg";

        rating = "8.199999999999999";
        releaseYear = 2010;
        title = "How to Train Your Dragon";
    }
)
```

**Update :**

How is it possible to display it and store the retrieved data so its easier to show it in `UITableView`.
i tried to do like :

```
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject objectForKey:@"image"]);
```

to get the whole images only but it crashes. i just need to get for example all the titles and store them in array and then display them `UITableView`.

Comment: This is not in JSON, this is already parsed for you as an `NSDictionary` (I'm referring to the root object)

Comment: To be more accurate, this is an `NSArray` you got here (I assume that you've just omitted some of the printed description) containing dictionaries that each one representing a movie. So instead of building collections with single properties (like titles or images) just stick to this collection and 'fill' your views from each of these objects. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: Will you provide me a sample ? @Alladinian

Comment: you responseObject store in NSMutableArray and use tableView Delegate method. @Aaoli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try this way to get data from `NSDictionary`

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    self.arrData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:responseObject];
    [self.tableView reloadData];// reload table data
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

TableView Delegate Method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       // your cell code here
      // indexPath.row(use in tableView) means your number of index to get value
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]);
    NSLog(@"title: %@", [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]);
    NSLog(@"rating: %@", [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"rating"]);
   NSLog(@"releaseYear: %@", [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"releaseYear"]);
   NSLog(@"genre: %@", [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"genre"]);// return array get value particular using array index 
}
```

Comment: I've a general question, if i need to get images from the web and display it, what is a good library to store the images and caching it ?

Comment: This answer only reads title or image, can't read rating or releaseYear, or genre. and i tried to read it but my app crashes!!

Comment: NSLog(@"genre: %@", [[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"genre"] objectAtIndex:0]); try this way @AaoIi

Comment: May you please join this room for chat, i may need your help? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83210/parsing-swift-and-tableview

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking returns already processed `JSON` in `responseObject` - and in your case it's an NSArray of NSDictionary objects inside it.

To access a single NSDictionary create an NSArray property (e.g. `resultArray`) and set it to `responseObject`, then you can access its objects by `resultArray[1]` (make sure to bounce check).

Then you can access the values of the `dictionary` by their keys (`myDictionary[@"title]` and so on).